# Maven trying to download file it doesnt have access too

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-2, maven-dependency-plugin

I am trying to build my maven project and every time I build I get the following error:

> Access denied to
>   http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/org/eclipse/jdt/core/3.2.3.v_686_R32x/core-3.2.3.v_686_R32x.pom.

I have tried to force clean and install.  I also tried blowing away the folder in .m2/repository.  When I try to build I see this come through:

> Downloading:
>   http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/org/eclipse/jdt/core/3.2.3.v_686_R32x/core-3.2.3.v_686_R32x.pom
>
> Downloading:
>   http://maven.softeu.cz/org/eclipse/jdt/core/3.2.3.v_686_R32x/core-3.2.3.v_686_R32x.pom

My pom.xml depencies look like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jahia.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>jahia-impl</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0-EE</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>castor</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jahia.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>jahia-taglib</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0-EE</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.42</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
        <artifactId>castor-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
        <artifactId>castor-xml</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

How can I keep maven from trying to download this or include it myself?!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC this is the old/disabled repo for JBoss. They've moved to Nexus. See https://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenRepository for all the details.